# C++ Singleton no symbols are loaded for this document

Tags: c++, singleton

I'm using the following technique for a logger class I'm implementing.  I have an initialize function in my Logger.  In debug mode, it steps right over the init() call when I call Logger::getInstance().init().  When I put a breakpoint inside the init() function there is a message that says "The breakpoint will currently not be hit.  No symbols are loaded for this document".  Do you know why this would be happening?

Logger.h file:

```
class Logger
{
private:
    Logger();
    ~Logger();
public:
    Logger(const Logger&) = delete;

    static Logger& getInstance()
    {
        static Logger mInstance;
        return mInstance;
    }

    void init();

}
```

My call in main:

```
Logger::getInstance().init();
```

I put my breakpoint in Logger.cpp:

```
void Logger::init()
{
    //Do stuff <----Break point here 
}
```

During Debug mode I hover over my breakpoint and get the message:
"The breakpoint will currently not be hit.  No symbols are loaded for this document"

Comment: how do you compile it?

Comment: Working in Visual Studio 2017

Comment: so like @Keyoted write - check on your project that all the files are included

Comment: I do have #include "Logger.h" line in my code where I'm calling init().

Comment: and where is the implementation of init()?

Answer (score 0):

That message may appear because you either aren't compiling without symbols, use the `-g` option in clang or gcc.

Additionally that may also happen because you are not compiling your `.h` file, note that functionality/code should be written in `.cpp` and the `.h` should have only signature.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why I wasn't hitting the breakpoints.  I wasn't creating the pdb file for the Logger.  I went into the Logger project properties and changed the Debug Information Format.

Working in Visual Studio 2017:

> Right Click on project in Solution Explorer -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format

Change from "None" to "Program Database"